# Error with importing hmm from hmmlearn in python3

Tags: python, hmmlearn, macos-ventura

[image]

facing this error when trying to import hmmlearn.hmm. Any suggestion on resolve this?

the filepath
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hmmlearn' has already these files.

[image]

But the error has a warning as

```
incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')
```

Any idea on how to resolve it?

Comment: Is this package supported on Apple M1? See also https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/issues/475

Comment: When you installed the hmmlearn package, were you given a choice of Intel or M1 architecture?

Comment: i tried with `pip3 install --upgrade --user hmmlearn` only & there was no option to give the architecture type. However, surprisingly `import hmmlearn' shows no error only `import hmmlearn.hmm` that gives me the error. Any clue on how to resolve this? @nick-odell @john-gordon

Comment: As others mentioned, the library is using a low level compiled module which is architecture dependent. The reason importing the main module does not throw any error is because it's just a list of modules and does not call any of the lower level APIs. Try using `hmmlearn.hmm` and you'll see it. Gotta check the package publisher to see if there is a proper version for your architecture.